# Why is the UpdateAsync method setting to null, false?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I would like to update only EMAIL in the database.

NOW field values in the database

```
Id = 1,
Email = email@site.com,
IsActiveSubscibe = true,
PurchaseToken = "sdsdsdsd",
AutoRenewing = true,
IsActiveSubscibe = true,
DataTime = DateTime.UtcNow
```

doing UPDATE (I want to update only email)

```
Models.User user = new Models.User
{
   Id = 1,
   Email = newEmail@site.com,

};
  await App.Database.UpdateUser(user);
```

SQLITE METHOD

```
public Task UpdateUser(User user)
{
  return database.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

After UPDATE. NOW field values in the database

```
Id = 1,
Email = newEmail@site.com,
IsActiveSubscibe = false,
PurchaseToken = null,
AutoRenewing = false
IsActiveSubscibe = false,
DataTime = null
```

The RESULT I would like to get

```
Id = 1,
Email = newEmail@site.com,
IsActiveSubscibe = true,
PurchaseToken = "sdsdsdsd",
AutoRenewing = true,
IsActiveSubscibe = true,
DataTime = DateTime.UtcNow
```

Comment: try fetch that record from database first and then edit the values and save (update)

Comment: alternative approach - talk to the database directly: `update Users set Email=@newEmail where Id=@id;` with `@newEmail` set to `newEmail@site.com` and `@id` set to `1` (optional: return something to indicate whether a row was updated or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are creating a new object

```
Models.User user = new Models.User
{
   Id = 1,
   Email = newEmail@site.com,

};
```

That only has 2 values, the Id and Email. All the other fields will be set to default: null for most of the objects, and false for the bool

So no matter what info you had before, it will be replaced.

First fetch the user (I used the ID, but it can be another field )and then modify.

```
Models.User userToModify= await App.Database.GetUserById(1);
userToModify.email= newEmail@site.com;
await App.Database.UpdateUser(userToModify);
```